# Websphere Application Server 6.0.2 not accepting xml file in shared libraries

Tags: websphere, classpath, libraries, shared

I am on WAS 6.0.2. I need an XML file in classpath for one of my applications.

Taking help from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427837/how-do-i-manage-the-classpath-in-websphere) , I've configured Shared Library "common" with node scope. The shared library has the following entry.

```
C:\WebSphere\AppServer\CommonLibs\Config.xml
```

I then associated the shared libary with my application. When I run the server, I see the following in the log.

```
[2/10/11 7:36:13:614 EST] 00000017 CompoundClass E   WSVR0120E: An error occurred processing 
C:\WebSphere\AppServer\CommonLibs\Config.xml
java.util.zip.ZipException: Error opening zip file     
C:\WebSphere\AppServer\CommonLibs\Config.xml
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:140)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:160)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:98)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.SinglePathClassProvider.buildContentsCache(SinglePathClassProvider.java:557)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.SinglePathClassProvider.<init>(SinglePathClassProvider.java:99)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.SinglePathClassProvider.create(SinglePathClassProvider.java:123)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.addPaths(CompoundClassLoader.java:234)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.JarClassLoader.addPaths(JarClassLoader.java:101)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ClassGraph.createClassLoaders(ClassGraph.java:472)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ClassGraph.calculate(ClassGraph.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ClassLoaderManager.initialize(ClassLoaderManager.java:204)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ClassLoaderManager.<init>(ClassLoaderManager.java:155)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:699)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:923)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$AppInitializer.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2214)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(ComponentImpl.java:304)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1498)
```

I guess the server only expects zip or jar files in the classpath. Please guide on how to include the XML file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by adding the classpath entry `C:\WebSphere\AppServer\CommonLibs` to

```
Application servers > server > Process Definition > Java Virtual Machine
```

using the admin console of Websphere. It works finally.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should try putting the xml file in a jar file.

See this question on how [Java: Load a resource contained in a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574809/java-load-a-resource-contained-in-a-jar)

Comment: In case a change is needed in the configuration file, I will not be able to simply edit the file then. An extra step of packaging the XML file in jar file will be added.